# Expected an operand but found <

Tags: javascript, java, javascript-objects

```
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();  
ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("Nashorn");  
engine.eval(Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("C:\\jsFunction.js"), 
 StandardCharsets.UTF_8));  
Invocable inv = (Invocable) engine;  
inv.invokeFunction("Running", "Running");
```

This is jsFunction.js

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>  
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>  
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Because of these script tags in my code jsFunction.js I'm getting the specified error.

```
var messageToSendEveryXTime;  
messageToSendEveryXTime = "Hie";  
setInterval(function(){  
    window.InputEvent = window.Event || window.InputEvent;   
    var d = new Date();   
    var event = new InputEvent('input', {bubbles: true});   
    var textbox = $('div._2S1VP');   
    textbox.textContent = messageToSendEveryXTime;  
    textbox.dispatchEvent(event); $("button._35EW6").click();  
}  
);
```

when I run this code I'm getting an error displaying

```
Expected an operand but found <
```

Comment: How exactly do you run this? Where is the DOM from? And `jQuery` ?

Comment: i run this on eclipse and this is a part of my code.

Comment: There is no `<` in the JS file you show. Are you sure you are reading the correct file? Try printing out the contents of the file to check.

Comment: sorry it was a mistake. Just now I edited the question and because of those script tags I'm getting the specified error.

Comment: The ScriptEngine only parses Javascript files, not HTML. Also, it will most likely not provide you with a browser DOM (so that there will not be a `window` or an `InputEvent`).

Comment: I'm using selenium web event to open a browser. If you are free contact me on sujithreddy290796@gmail.com, I'll send you the whole code